# Try to find minimal value of weighted numbers

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-optimization

Given a data set, I need to find the minimal value of the total values divided by the total weights.
The data sets are of arbitrary length (each data set may have a different length, but the data set and the corresponding weights have the same lengths).

Considering a simple example:

```
 DataSetOne [500, 45]
 WeightsOfSetOne = [10, 1]

 DataSetTwo [850, 90]
 WeightsOfSetTwo = [10, 1]
```

Given these data sets, you can get 4 results.

```
     [1] (500 + 850)/(10+10) = 1350/20 = 67.5
     [2] (500 + 90)/(10+1) = 590/11 = 53.6
     [3] (45 + 850)/(1+10) = 895/11 = 81.4
     [4] (45 + 90)/(1 + 1) = 135/2 = 67.5
```

In this case, we see that [2] gives the optimal solution. However, this is a brute force method and I would rather calculate it Mathematically (if possible) because brute force simply is not possible since the number of possibilities scales exponentially with the number of data sets.

The approach I tried was as follows:

For each of the values with their corresponding weights of Data_set_one:

Start with a (value + weight) from the first Data set.
Then for all the other data sets:

Traverse each data set and choose the option in the data set that gives the minimum value for Total value so far/Total Weight so far.

However. This approach failed with the data set below.

```
            Data_set_one_values: [50, 72, 9]
            Data_set_one_weights [52, 32, 3]
            Data_set_two_values: [87, 63, 0]
            Data_set_two_weights [43, 88, 36]
            Data_set_three_values: [83, 16, 94]
            Data_set_three_weights [38, 22, 56]
            Data_set_four_values: [22, 61, 37]
            Data_set_four_weights: [25, 13, 55]
            Data_set_five_values: [1, 15, 52]
            Data_set_five_weights: [53, 80, 43]
```

If there is no exact way to calculate this except a brute-force method by calculating all combinations, is there a way perhaps that I can get an approximation that works?

Comment: One thing you can do, no matter how you solve the rest of the problem, is throw out infeasible values. In your fourth data set of your last example, the highest value $61$ with the lowest weight $13$ will never be selected; likewise $52$ with weight $43$ in the fifth.

Comment: Those are the most obvious, but you can do a bit better than that. For instance, in the second data set, $87$ with weight $43$ can only be preferable to $0$ with weight $36$ if $7V-87W-3132>0$, where $V$ and $W$ are the sums of values and weights, respectively, from the remaining data sets. But $V\le72+87+94+61=314$ and $W\ge3+36+22+13=74$, so this is impossible, so $87$ with weight $43$ can also be excluded.

Comment: In the first data set, $72$ with weight $32$ is dominated by $50$ with weight $52$ (even though it could win against $9$ with weight $3$), so that can also go.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, the data set I generated was with random integers till 100, just for the verification of my method. My method generated a good outcome most of the time, or an outcome that was close to it, but I prefer an exact approach to my problem.

Comment: My suggestion to eliminate infeasible values is exact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to use mixed integer linear programming.  For each set $i$ and item $j$, let $v_{i,j}$ denote the value and $w_{i,j}$ denote the weight, and let binary decision variable $x_{i,j}$ indicate whether the item is selected.  The problem is to minimize 
$$\frac{\displaystyle{\sum_{i,j} v_{i,j} x_{i,j}}}{\displaystyle{\sum_{i,j} w_{i,j} x_{i,j}}}$$
subject to
$$\sum_j x_{i,j} = 1$$ for all $i$.

You can linearize the fractional objective via a [Charnes-Cooper transformation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3500493/doing-a-charnes-cooper-transformation-with-matrices-and-an-zero-one-constraint).

Here is SAS code for your second instance:

```
data indata;
   input set item value weight;
   datalines;
1 1 50 52
1 2 72 32
1 3  9  3
2 1 87 43
2 2 63 88
2 3  0 36
3 1 83 38
3 2 16 22
3 3 94 56
4 1 22 25
4 2 61 13
4 3 37 55
5 1  1 53
5 2 15 80
5 3 52 43
;

proc optmodel;
   /* declare parameters and read data */
   set <num,num> SET_ITEM;
   num value {SET_ITEM};
   num weight {SET_ITEM};
   read data indata into SET_ITEM=[set item] value weight;
   set SETS = setof {<i,j> in SET_ITEM} i;

   /* declare original variable and constraint */
   var X {SET_ITEM} binary;
   con OneItemPerSet {i in SETS}:
      sum {<(i),j> in SET_ITEM} X[i,j] = 1;

   /* declare linearization variables, objective, and constraint */
   var T >= 0 <= 1 / min {<i,j> in SET_ITEM} weight[i,j];
   var Y {SET_ITEM} >= 0 <= T.ub;
   min LinearizedRatio = sum {<i,j> in SET_ITEM} value[i,j] * Y[i,j];
   con DenominatorOne:
      sum {<i,j> in SET_ITEM} weight[i,j] * Y[i,j] = 1;
   con Linearize1 {i in SETS}:
      sum {<(i),j> in SET_ITEM} Y[i,j] = T;
   con Linearize2 {<i,j> in SET_ITEM}:
      Y[i,j] <= Y[i,j].ub * X[i,j];

   /* call MILP solver */
   solve;

   /* report solution */
   print X value weight;
quit;
```

The resulting optimal solution, with minimum ratio $48/139=0.345$, is:
\begin{matrix}
i &j &x &v &w\\ 
\hline
1 &1 &0 &50 &52 \\
1 &2 &0 &72 &32 \\
1 &3 &1 &9 &3 \\
2 &1 &0 &87 &43 \\
2 &2 &0 &63 &88 \\
2 &3 &1 &0 &36 \\
3 &1 &0 &83 &38 \\
3 &2 &1 &16 &22 \\
3 &3 &0 &94 &56 \\
4 &1 &1 &22 &25 \\
4 &2 &0 &61 &13 \\
4 &3 &0 &37 &55 \\
5 &1 &1 &1 &53 \\
5 &2 &0 &15 &80\\ 
5 &3 &0 &52 &43
\end{matrix}

Comment: I looked into your answer and it seems very well explained, thanks for taking your time to answer it. I will program this solution in tomorrow and if it works on the data sets I will accept your answer!

Comment: I looked into it, but from there, how do I find what the optimal y is? The input to that function is still a 1D vector which determines with paths you choose, and I don't see how I can get a solution from the linearisation without trying for all possible y's (brute force method)

Comment: After the linearization, you would call a mixed integer linear programming (MILP) solver, which is typically orders of magnitude faster than brute force.

Comment: The problem is solved. I posted my solution and code I made for it, thanks a lot for your help, accepted your answer, and have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Using the Accepted answer of Rob Pratt, 
an installation guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oA86HCkCg5k (till 2:40)
and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sf59_7r8QSY 
to get a general idea on how to work with the IBM CPlex.
```

I get the following code. (Java)

```
 import ilog.concert.IloLinearNumExpr;
import ilog.concert.IloNumExpr;
import ilog.concert.IloNumVar;
import ilog.cplex.IloCplex;

import java.util.*;

public class TestFileTwo {

public static long Time = 0L;

public static void main(String args[]){
    boolean TestApproximation = true;
    boolean TestMILPs = true;
    boolean TestSimulation = true;
    boolean PrintDataSet = false;
    boolean TestDataOne = false;
    boolean TestDataTwo = false;

    ArrayList<int[]> ValueList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<int[]> WeightList = new ArrayList<>();
    int DataSets = 10;
    int ElementsPerDataSet = 3;
    if(!TestDataOne && !TestDataTwo) {
        for (int i = 0; i < DataSets; i++) {
            int[] ValueArray = new int[ElementsPerDataSet];
            int[] WeightArray = new int[ElementsPerDataSet];
            for (int j = 0; j < ElementsPerDataSet; j++) {
                ValueArray[j] = GetRandom(100);
                WeightArray[j] = GetRandom(100);
            }
            ValueList.add(ValueArray);
            WeightList.add(WeightArray);
        }
    }

    if(PrintDataSet) {
        for (int i = 0; i < DataSets; i++) {
            System.out.println("ValueList.add(new int[] " + Arrays.toString(ValueList.get(i)).replace("[", "{").replace("]", "};"));
            System.out.println("WeightList.add(new int[] " + Arrays.toString(WeightList.get(i)).replace("[", "{").replace("]", "};"));
        }
    }
    if(TestDataOne) {
        ValueList.add(new int[]{50, 72, 9});
        WeightList.add(new int[]{52, 32, 3});
        ValueList.add(new int[]{87, 63, 0});
        WeightList.add(new int[]{43, 88, 36});
        ValueList.add(new int[]{83, 16, 94});
        WeightList.add(new int[]{38, 22, 56});
        ValueList.add(new int[]{22, 61, 37});
        WeightList.add(new int[]{25, 13, 55});
        ValueList.add(new int[]{1, 15, 52});
        WeightList.add(new int[]{53, 80, 43});
    }else if(TestDataTwo) {
        ValueList.add(new int[]{500, 45, 50, 510});
        WeightList.add(new int[]{10, 1, 1, 11});
        ValueList.add(new int[]{850, 90});
        WeightList.add(new int[]{10, 1});
    }

    long CurrentNanonTime = System.nanoTime();

    if(TestSimulation) {
        GetLowestFrom(ValueList, WeightList);
        System.out.println("Calculating From Simulations: " + (System.nanoTime() - CurrentNanonTime)/Math.pow(10,9));
        CurrentNanonTime = System.nanoTime();
    }
    if(TestApproximation) {
        GetLowestFromUsingMath(ValueList, WeightList);
        System.out.println("Approximation by deciding optimal averages: " + (System.nanoTime() - CurrentNanonTime)/Math.pow(10,9));
        CurrentNanonTime = System.nanoTime();
    }
    if(TestMILPs) {
        Time = System.nanoTime();
        SolveModel(ValueList, WeightList);
        System.out.println("Mixed-Integer Linearisation problem solver:" + (System.nanoTime() - CurrentNanonTime)/Math.pow(10,9));
    }
}

public static int GetRandom(int Max){
    return ((int) (Math.random() * (Max + 1)));
}


public static double GetLowestFromUsingMath(ArrayList<int[]> ValueList, ArrayList<int[]> WeightList){
    int Datasets = ValueList.size();
    int[] FirstValues = ValueList.get(0);
    int[] FirstWeights = WeightList.get(0);
    int[][] Vars = new int[FirstValues.length][];
    for(int i = 0; i < Vars.length; i++){
        Vars[i] = new int[] {FirstValues[i], FirstWeights[i]};
    }


    ArrayList<int[]> FinalList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<int[]> FinalPathList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int Startingpoint = 0; Startingpoint < Vars.length; Startingpoint++) {
        int[] PathsTaken = new int[Datasets];
        PathsTaken[0] = Startingpoint;
        int[] Total = Arrays.copyOf(Vars[Startingpoint], Vars[Startingpoint].length);
        for (int i = 1; i < Datasets; i++) {
            int[] Values = ValueList.get(i);
            int[] LowestValues = new int[Values.length];
            int[] Weights = WeightList.get(i);
            double Average = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            int LowestNumberIndex = 0;
            for(int ValueTest = 0; ValueTest < Values.length; ValueTest++){
                double NewVar = (((double) Total[0] + Values[ValueTest])/(Total[1] + Weights[ValueTest]));
                if(NewVar < Average){
                    Average = NewVar;
                    LowestNumberIndex = ValueTest;
                    LowestValues[0] = Values[ValueTest];
                    LowestValues[1] = Weights[ValueTest];
                }
            }
            PathsTaken[i] = LowestNumberIndex;
            Total[0] = Total[0] + LowestValues[0];
            Total[1] = Total[1] + LowestValues[1];
        }
        FinalList.add(Total);
        FinalPathList.add(PathsTaken);
    }

    double Average = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int[] Dummy = new int[] {0,0};
    int[] OptimalPath = null;
    for(int i = 0; i < FinalList.size(); i++){
        int[] Values = FinalList.get(i);
        double AVar = ((double) Values[0])/Values[1];
        if(AVar < Average){
            Average = AVar;
            Dummy = Values;
            OptimalPath = FinalPathList.get(i);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("[Approximation] "+Arrays.toString(Dummy) + " With average of: " + Average + " Path taken: " + Arrays.toString(OptimalPath));
    return Average;

}

public static double GetLowestFrom(ArrayList<int[]> ValueList, ArrayList<int[]> WeightList){
    int[] MaxArray = new int[ValueList.size()];
    int[] OptimalArray = new int[ValueList.size()];
    int[] IterationArray = new int[ValueList.size()];
    for(int i = 0; i < ValueList.size(); i++){
        MaxArray[i] = ValueList.get(i).length  - 1;
        IterationArray[i] = 0;
    }

    double Outcome = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    while(true){
        double Value = 0;
        double Weight = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < IterationArray.length; i++){
            Value += ValueList.get(i)[IterationArray[i]];
            Weight += WeightList.get(i)[IterationArray[i]];
        }
        double Average = Value/Weight;
        if(Average < Outcome){
            Outcome = Average;
            OptimalArray = Arrays.copyOf(IterationArray, IterationArray.length);
        }
        IterationArray = GetIncrementedArray(MaxArray, IterationArray);
        if(IterationArray == null){
            break;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("[Simulation] "+"The optimal Array is: " + Arrays.toString(OptimalArray) + " With average of: " + Outcome);
    return -1;
}

public static void SolveModel(ArrayList<int[]> ValueList, ArrayList<int[]> WeightList){
    double TotalWeight;
    double TotalValues = 0;

    int Datasets = ValueList.size();
    int[] NumberTaken = new int[Datasets];
    int[] DatasetLength = new int[Datasets];
    int[][] Values = new int[Datasets][];
    int[][] Weights = new int[Datasets][];
    for(int i = 0; i < Datasets; i++){
        int[] DummyValArray = ValueList.get(i);
        int[] DummyWeiArray = WeightList.get(i);
        int[] ValueArray = Arrays.copyOf(DummyValArray, DummyValArray.length);
        Values[i] = ValueArray;
        int[] WeightArray = Arrays.copyOf(DummyWeiArray, DummyWeiArray.length);
        Weights[i] = WeightArray;
        DatasetLength[i] = DummyValArray.length;
    }

    try {
        IloCplex model = new IloCplex();

        IloNumVar y[][] =new IloNumVar[Datasets][];
        /*
         * Defining
         * This means that I define the t (inverse of sum of weights of path taken)
         * as a variable between 0 and 2.1 Billion
         * */
        IloNumVar t = model.numVar(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE, "t");

        /*
         * Defining
         * This means that I define all y values as variables between 0 and 2.1 Billion
         * */
        for(int i=0;i<Datasets;i++) {
            y[i] = new IloNumVar[DatasetLength[i]];
            for (int j = 0; j < DatasetLength[i]; j++) {
                String varName = "y" + (i + 1) + "" + (j + 1) + "";
                y[i][j] = model.numVar(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE, varName);
            }
        }

        /*
         * Defining
         * This means you define the model as a lineair numerical expression
         * */
        IloLinearNumExpr objective = model.linearNumExpr();

        /*
         * Linear expression.
         * This means that I sum over all the Values
         * */
        for(int datasetIndex = 0; datasetIndex < Datasets; datasetIndex++){
            for(int elementIndex = 0; elementIndex < DatasetLength[datasetIndex]; elementIndex++){
                objective.addTerm(y[datasetIndex][elementIndex], Values[datasetIndex][elementIndex]);
            }
        }

        /*
         * Constraint
         * This means that the sum of all y's of one data set is variable t.
         * */
        for(int datasetIndex = 0; datasetIndex < Datasets; datasetIndex++) {
            model.addEq(model.sum(y[datasetIndex]), t);
        }

        /*
         * Constraint
         * This part means that the Multiplication of weight and y must be one
         * */
        IloNumExpr[] wys = new IloNumExpr[Datasets];
        for(int i=0;i<Datasets;i++) {
            IloNumExpr[] elements = new IloNumExpr[DatasetLength[i]];
            for (int j = 0; j < DatasetLength[i]; j++) {
                elements[j] = model.prod(y[i][j] ,Weights[i][j]);
            }
            wys[i] = model.sum(elements);
        }
        model.addEq(model.sum(wys), 1);

        /*
         * Objective
         * This part signals that the objective is to minimize the function.
         * */
        model.addMinimize(objective);

        if(model.solve()){
            System.out.println("t = " + model.getValue(t));

            for(int datasetIndex = 0; datasetIndex < Datasets; datasetIndex++){
                for(int elementIndex = 0; elementIndex < DatasetLength[datasetIndex]; elementIndex++){
                    if(model.getValue(y[datasetIndex][elementIndex]) != 0){
                        NumberTaken[datasetIndex] = elementIndex;
                        TotalValues += Values[datasetIndex][elementIndex];
                    }
                }
            }
            TotalWeight = Math.pow(model.getValue(t), -1);
            System.out.println("[MILP] "+"Total Value: " + TotalValues + " Total Weight: " + TotalWeight + " Value/Weight: " + TotalValues/TotalWeight);
            System.out.println("[MILP] "+"Path: taken " + Arrays.toString(NumberTaken));
            System.out.println("[MILP] "+"Time taken = " + ((System.nanoTime() - Time)/(Math.pow(10,9))));
        }else{
            System.out.println("[MILP] "+"An optimal solution has not been found.");
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static int[] GetIncrementedArray(int[] MaxArray, int[] ArrayToIncrement){
    if(GetIndex(MaxArray, ArrayToIncrement) == -1){
        return null;
    }
    int[] ResultingArray = Arrays.copyOf(ArrayToIncrement, ArrayToIncrement.length);
    ResultingArray[0]++;
    for(int i = 0; i < ArrayToIncrement.length; i++){
        if(ResultingArray[i] > MaxArray[i]){
            ResultingArray[i] = 0;
            ResultingArray[i+1]++;
        }else{
            return ResultingArray;
        }
    }
    return null;
}


public static int GetIndex(int[] Array1, int[] Array2){
    for(int i = 0; i < Array1.length; i++){
        if(Array1[i] != Array2[i]){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

}

This code contains my failed attempt to calculate it mathematically (called approximation, Calculating by simulation (brute force) and the mixed-integer linear programming (MILP) solver. I hope this is useful to someone :)