# Transfer a nonlieanear function to a linear function

Tags: linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, integer-programming, approximation-theory, linearization

I'm using Java to solve a maximization problem in Cplex. My objective function is quite complex. In a nutshell, there are two parts, A and B. Both of them contain variables.

My goal is to maximize A/B, but Cplex does now allow me to do A/B. I guess A/B will make the objective been nonlinear, which cannot be solved by Cplex.

My question is, is it possible to use a linear or almost-linear function to mimic A/B (Assume A and B are linear)?  For example, A-B can roughly approximate A/B. I have tried to use A-B as the objective function, but the result is bad. So can we have a better way to approximate A/B?

Many thanks.

Comment: This is too vague a question to answer. Does maximizing $\log(A/B) = \log(A) - \log(B)$ help?

Comment: What types of expressions are $A$ and $B$?

Comment: Do you have a positive lower bound on $B$? This optimisation will be incredibly difficuly if $B$ can get arbitrarily close to 0.

Comment: This is a set cover problem. A is the gain from the selected items. B is the total cost of the selected items.

Comment: So both $A$ and $B$ are linear functions of binary variables?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $A$ and $B$ are linear functions of binary variables, you can linearize the objective exactly by applying a Charnes-Cooper transformation, followed by a linearization of the resulting products.  See [my answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3500493/doing-a-charnes-cooper-transformation-with-matrices-and-an-zero-one-constraint/3500608#3500608).