# How to minimize the gap between a fractional linear expression with a constant value?

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, mixed-integer-programming, linearization, cvx, cvxpy

how to minimize the gap between a fractional linear expression with a constant value

I have a selection problem with objective function like:
$$
min\mid\frac{\sum a_i\cdot x_i}{\sum b_i\cdot x_i}-\alpha\mid
$$

Let me explain this objective function: we want the production efficiency as close to 50% as possible. Yes, we do not pursue max production efficiency.

As it is a **selection problem**, $x_i$ is binary (0 or 1). $a, b$ are constant vector and $\alpha$ is a constant scalar.

I know how to maximize a linear fractional programming problem (MILFP) via Charnes-Cooper transformation. And I know how to handle a absolute value in objective function. But I want to know how to handle a problem like that.

My solution to MILFP, inspired by [Charnes-Cooper transformation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3500493/doing-a-charnes-cooper-transformation-with-matrices-and-an-zero-one-constraint) and [Linear-fractional_programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-fractional_programming):

​   original:
$$
min\frac{\sum a_i\cdot x_i}{\sum b_i\cdot x_i}
$$
​   converted:
$$
min(\sum a_i\cdot y_i) \\ st. \\
\sum b_i \cdot y_i = 1 \\
0 <= y_i <= M \cdot x_i, \ for \ each \ i \\
y_i -t<=M\cdot(1-x[i]), \ for \ each \ i \\
y_i -t>=-M\cdot(1-x[i]), \ for \ each \ i
$$
where t and y are float random variables.

My solution to absolute value in objective function:

​   original:
$$
min\mid \sum x_i-\alpha\mid
$$
​   converted:
$$
min(z) \\ st. \\
z>=\sum x_i - \alpha \\
z>=-(\sum x_i - \alpha)
$$
I wonder how to combine the two solutions together. I tried but it didnot work.

Comment: You have not indicated what $t$ is, and I suspect your last constraint on $y_i - t$ should be $\ge$ rather than $\le.$

Comment: @prubin, tks for your comment. The question has been modified.

Comment: Are your $b_{i}$ coefficients positive?

Comment: @BrianBorchers $a_i$, $b_i$, $\alpha$ are all positive value and $x_i$ is binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce continuous decision variable $z$, with bounds $[0,M]$.  To avoid the absolute value, minimize $z$ subject to
\begin{align}
z &\ge \frac{\sum_i a_i x_i}{\sum_i b_i x_i} - \alpha \\
z &\ge -\frac{\sum_i a_i x_i}{\sum_i b_i x_i} + \alpha
\end{align}
To avoid the ratios, multiply both sides by the denominator $\sum_i b_i x_i$:
\begin{align}
z \sum_i b_i x_i &\ge \sum_i a_i x_i - \alpha \sum_i b_i x_i \\
z \sum_i b_i x_i &\ge -\sum_i a_i x_i + \alpha \sum_i b_i x_i
\end{align}
To linearize the product $z x_i$, introduce continuous decision variable $y_i$ and impose linear constraints:
\begin{align}
\sum_i b_i y_i &\ge \sum_i (a_i - \alpha b_i) x_i \tag1\label1\\
\sum_i b_i y_i &\ge \sum_i (-a_i + \alpha b_i) x_i \tag2\label2\\
0 \le y_i &\le M x_i &&\text{for all $i$}\tag3\label3 \\
0 \le z - y_i &\le M (1-x_i) &&\text{for all $i$} \tag4\label4
\end{align}
Now minimize $z$ subject to \eqref{1} through \eqref{4}.

---

Alternatively, you can replace big-M constraints \eqref{3} and \eqref{4} with indicator constraints
\begin{align}
x_i = 0 &\implies y_i = 0  &&\text{for all $i$} \\
x_i = 1 &\implies y_i = z &&\text{for all $i$} 
\end{align}

---

You can reduce the number of nonzero constraint coefficients by introducing a decision variable $r$ to represent the ratio and then linearizing $y_i=r x_i$:
\begin{align}
z&\ge r-\alpha \\
z&\ge \alpha-r \\
\sum_i b_i y_i &= \sum_i a_i x_i\\
0 \le y_i &\le M x_i &&\text{for all $i$} \\
0 \le r - y_i &\le M (1-x_i) &&\text{for all $i$} 
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Your algorithm works very well. But based on your answer, constraints (3) and (4) have to be imposed on **each** $y_i$. What if  **x** is a very large vector like $[x_1, x_2 \cdots x_{100000}  ]$? In that case we have 100000 binary variables and we have to construct a problem with more that 200000 constraints which make this problem impossible to solve. Do you have any idea how to improve the performance?

Comment: What solver are you using? One approach is to dynamically generate these constraints only if they are violated. Another idea is to use indicator constraints instead of big-M constraints.

Comment: TKS! I am using [CVXPY](https://www.cvxpy.org/) with CBC solver and CPLEX solver. I am confused why it can reduce the number of constraints via replacing big-M constraints with indicator constraints. And it is a good idea to introduce a new decision variable $r$ to represent the ratio but it does not look like it can help reduce the number of constraints

Comment: Introducing $r$ yields the same number of constraints but fewer nonzero constraint *coefficients*.